# Postman file upload boundary

Tags: rest, file-upload, postman

I'm trying to upload a file with my REST POST request. It is not working out. When i try to look at the request postman give:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 44262
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------085877645320272030820682
Host: localhost
```

Why there is a boundry? why postman doesn't return the file that i uploaded?

Comment: are you sure about the content-Type for this request ? Content-Type: mulipart/form-data requires boundary corresponding to the content in the Body.

Comment: what should i do with content-Type? I left it as it is as some people where saying that postman overwrites it anyway

Comment: Need more details on how you are attaching an file to the POST request.

Comment: I leave the header as it is. I set the body to form-data, then add a key as a file and upload the picture. When I try to return the request in my server I get the message i put in my post

Comment: have you tried adding the attachment under 'binary' ?

Comment: Yes, this works fine actually. so How do I access the attached image through binary?

Answer (score 0):

Adding an attachment as 'binary' would solve the POST request problem in your case.

If you would like to download the same attachment, there should be an GET request towards  the API.

If that doesn't solve, you should describe your issue better with some pictures to understand better.